# Twilio Device defined in sticky Service is not starting activity if app closed

Tags: android, service, twilio

I need to be able to receive incoming Twilio calls regardless of whether the app is currently running or not.

Once the user has started the app and logged into our server, I start the service shown below.

The Service is started sticky, and at no point is `stopService` or `stopSelf` etc ever called, so the service should still be running after the App is closed.

- When the App is running, `IncomingCallActivity` starts fine in response to a Twilio call.
- If the App is in the background, `IncomingCallActivity` still starts fine in response to a Twilio call.
- **If however the App is closed, `IncomingCallActivity` no longer starts in response to a Twilio call.**

**Why isn't `IncomingCallActivity` started if the App has been closed??**

```
public class CallService extends Service implements Twilio.InitListener, DeviceListener, ConnectionListener {

    private Device mDevice;
    private Connection mConnection;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        registerBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // Initialize the Twilio SDK if required
        if (!Twilio.isInitialized()) {
            Twilio.initialize(getApplicationContext(), this);
        } else {
            getCapabilityToken("CallService", getUser());
        }

        ...

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        // Unregister broadcast receiver
        final LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitialized() {
        getCapabilityToken("CallService", getUser());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {

    }

    private void getCapabilityToken(String string, User user) {
        // Request the capability token from the server.
        ...
    }

    protected void setCapabilityToken() {

        // Create device using the capability token
        mDevice = Twilio.createDevice(getUser().capabilityToken, this);

        // Set pending intent for Twilio device    
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncomingCallActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mDevice.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);

        // Broadcast that CallService is ready, to any registered receivers
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(App.ACTION__TWILIO_SERVICE_READY);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

    public void connect() {
        mConnection = mDevice.connect(null /* parameters */, null /* ConnectionListener */);
        if (mConnection == null) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    private void answerCall(Device device, Connection connection) {

        if (mConnection != null) {
            mConnection.disconnect();
        }

        mConnection = connection;
        mConnection.accept();
    }

    /**
     * BroadcastReceiver
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            final String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action) {

                case App.ACTION__CAPABILITY_TOKEN_OBTAINED:
                    setCapabilityToken();
                    break;

                case App.ACTION__CONNECT:
                    connect();
                    break;

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onStartListening(Device device) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopListening(Device device) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopListening(Device device, int i, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean receivePresenceEvents(Device device) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPresenceChanged(Device device, PresenceEvent presenceEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnecting(Connection connection) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Connection connection) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(Connection connection) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(Connection connection, int i, String s) {

    }
}
```

## Edit:

To clarify how I've declared my services etc, here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="au.com.encall.encall"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".IncomingCallActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <service android:name=".services.CallService"/>
        <service android:name=".services.DownloadService"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />

        <meta-data
            ... />

        ...

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using twilio demo  than You need to service in Androidmenifest

```
<service android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService" android:exported="false" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
```

its working for me.

[twilio provide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) their own service. so you need to just declare it on menifest.so does't need to create new service.

jusr remove this service and put it on android menifest.it will automatically start after app close.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I already have that in my `AndroidManifest`, except that I have `android:stopWithTask="false"` because I don't want the TwilioClientService stopping if the task does.

Answer (score 0):

**Its Work for me no need extra service**

```
<service android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService" android:exported="false" android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

But How can we Handle if token is **Expired** ? At that time `IncomingCallActivity`  no longer starts